How to specify Coordinate Reference Systems using GeoServer's REST API?
I'm integrating GeoServer's REST API into our software and I can't find how to specify Coordinate Reference Systems (CRS) when creating a Shapefile datasource or when updating a layer.
What I currently do via API is:

create a workspace
add 2 datastores to that workspace by uploading 2 Shapefiles.
create a layer group combining the previous 2 layers that were automatically created.

If I leave the default EPSG:404000 on the 2 layers then they don't show up in Leaflet because the bbox param is wrong. I have to manually change EPSG:404000 (default value set by API) to EPSG:4326 in both layers to have the layer group show up in Leaflet (bbox param is now correct).
I can specify a CRS value when creating a layer group via API but not when creating layers.
If I pass
<attribution>
  <title>hello</title>
</attribution>
<bounds>
  <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
</bounds>

then layer's title is changed but not the CRS.
How can I change the CRS value of a layer via API?
Thanks!

As always the trick with any REST API is to look at the response from a correct layer (though in this case the real trick is to fix your shapefiles), so http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/topp/datastores/states_shapefile/featuretypes/states.xml:
<featureType>
  <name>states</name>
  <nativeName>states</nativeName>
  <namespace>
    <name>topp</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/namespaces/topp.xml" type="application/xml"/>
  </namespace>
  <title>USA Population</title>
  <abstract>This is some census data on the states.</abstract>
  <keywords>
    <string>census</string>
    <string>united</string>
    <string>boundaries</string>
    <string>state</string>
    <string>states</string>
  </keywords>
  <nativeCRS>GEOGCS[&quot;GCS_WGS_1984&quot;,
  DATUM[&quot;WGS_1984&quot;,
    SPHEROID[&quot;WGS_1984&quot;, 6378137.0, 298.257223563]],
  PRIMEM[&quot;Greenwich&quot;, 0.0],
  UNIT[&quot;degree&quot;, 0.017453292519943295],
  AXIS[&quot;Longitude&quot;, EAST],
  AXIS[&quot;Latitude&quot;, NORTH]]</nativeCRS>
  <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
  <nativeBoundingBox>
    <minx>-124.73142200000001</minx>
    <maxx>-66.969849</maxx>
    <miny>24.955967</miny>
    <maxy>49.371735</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </nativeBoundingBox>
  <latLonBoundingBox>
    <minx>-124.731422</minx>
    <maxx>-66.969849</maxx>
    <miny>24.955967</miny>
    <maxy>49.371735</maxy>
    <crs>EPSG:4326</crs>
  </latLonBoundingBox>
  <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>
  <enabled>true</enabled>
  ...

So it seems that you can specify the Native CRS and default CRS in the XML as either a WKT String or an EPSG code, in your case you want to override the native CRS (EPSG:40400, which means unknown) with EPSG:4326 (if that's what your data is actually in) so when modifying the featuretype you need to POST at least:
<featureType>
 <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
 <projectionPolicy>FORCE_DECLARED</projectionPolicy>     
</featureType>

But I suspect you'll also need to set the latLonBoundingBox unless it looks right any way.

Hi Ian, thanks for your message.
A GET call is the first thing I did actually and I got nothing regarding CRS or lat/lon. Only defaultStyle, resource, queryable and attribution (where I can see title being changed). That being said, I guess I should GET a featureType and not a layer. I'll give it a go.

a Layer is a combination of a featureType and one or more Styles.

Updating the featureType did the trick. Thank you, Ian.
